# Getting attributes value of a button in code behind on button click

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to get value of any attribute of button in WPF in my code behind On_ButtonClick method how can i get it?

i need the value of "Binding id", how can i get the this value in my code behind, in which attribute should i keep this "Binding Id" so that i can get it in my code behind

i have tried using `this.<attributeName>` but this is not working

this is my code behind

```
private void addToCall( object sender , RoutedEventArgs e )// add this perticular dcotor to call
{
    string id = <ValueSource of Binding ID>
}
```

this is my button,

```
{
    button Content="add" DataContext="{Binding id}" Command="{Binding id}" Tag="{Binding id}" Click="addToCall" MouseEnter="Button_OnMouseEnter" MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave" 
}
```

in code behind when i check the "sender" it's showing me the correct value which is an integer "xxx" but i dont know how to assign this value to variable id in my cod behind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the sender in your click handler to get the properties of the button.

```
private void addToCall( object sender , RoutedEventArgs e )// add this perticular dcotor to call
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    if(btn != null)
    {
        string id = btn.<attributeName>;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank @Aakanksha this resolved my issue I will mark it as solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Xaml:**

You can add attribute in button control like `myAttribute="AttribValue"`

```
<Button Click="button1_Click" myAttribute="AttribValue" Height="23" Margin="0,0,5,0" Name="button1" Width="75">Submit</Button>
```

**C# code behind:**

You can get that attribute value in button click event like below:

```
void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    var theAttributeValue = button.Attributes["myAttribute"].ToString();
}
```